# Dynamically add Relative Layouts that have the same layout as base

Tags: java, android

How do I dynamically generate a RelativeLayout based on a xml layout (posted below)? The relative layouts are being put in a linear layout that is the child of a scroll view.

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/post_0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/op_username"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Username" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/op_username"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="31dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
                    tools:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that you've all the Images and their TextView's texts in your Database, then create a `RecyclerView` (if there are a relatively huge number of items) or a simple `ListView`, and then create a CustomAdapter class to add your RelativeLayout to your main `ListView`/ `ScrollView`/ `RecyclerView`.

To completely implement this first you need to have an Item class which can store a user's Username and Image ( please note that you need to pass Image URI as a string) in an Object.

```
public class Items {

    private final int id;
    private final String image;

    public Items(int id,String image){
        this.name=name;
        this.image=image;
    }
    //Include all the Getters and Setters here
}
```

Then assuming you've all your elements into an `ArrayList<Items>`, then you need to implement an Adapter class, called CustomAdaper which extends ArrayAdapter and need to write a function for `getView` to get a particular view to fill in your `ScrollView`/`RecyclerView`/`ListView`

I've found a link to help you implement a CustomAdapter [here](https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial).

And finally in the MainActivity, you've to add few lines,

```
final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);    //name of list view file
final ArrayList<Items> arrayList = dbHelper.retrieveFromDB(); // Name of the Database class and the function to retrieve all the elements into an ArrayList in that class
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this /* The current Context */, R.layout.list_item, arrayList); // Create an object of custom adapter initialize it with the desired data (in this case the arrayList) and the layout required ( layout mentioned in the question) 
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a dynamic list that can have a large number of items use a recyclerview and place that relative layout inside a cardview.
If the dynamic list has a maximum potential number of items that are also few in number, you could add the relative layout and hide them, then populate and then show them as needed, but i advice you lean toward the former.